# How to add Microformat for Vocabulary words?

Tags: microformats, rdfa, rich-snippets

Does anyone know how Quizlet builds the search result data with "Term" and "Definition" headers and vocabulary/ definition data in their Google search results metadata? Is it microformatting or some other method?

For reference:

the search result displayed (3rd listing) - http://bit.ly/WuES0X
the actual webpage - http://quizlet.com/4835950/web-20-flash-cards/

Answer (score 0):

microformat `rel="tag">` is for tagging posts and paging by subject..essentially the same thing only you need to apply `a` elements around your vocab words, so idk if that's optimal for you. if it is entirely vocab, or rather, a glossary, you could wrap it all up nicely in a `dl` like so:

`<dl>

  <dt><dfn><a href="tags/tag.html" rel="tag">tag</a></dfn></dt>

  <dd><p>definition of tag.</p></dd>

</dl>`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. So if I restructure my content to a definition list, the google search results will show the content similarly to the first link above?

Comment: the microformats will provide the nice details displayed in serps. or schema.org technologies provide the same features. the definition list is just semantic, if that's what your doing. atm it should provide some benefit as opposed to a bunch of divs...how much? i have no clue. in the future it'll matter more.

Comment: Thanks. This does help for better refactoring, but I am looking for a valid solution for how to implement microformats/rdfa properly. The schema.org references don't seem to have examples on how to use them for vocabulary terms and definitions. I only see examples for other types of data.

Comment: what part about of that do you think is invalid? there are microformats implemented.